# Pandas 'None' type does not apply to all empty columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have some code that uses the 'openpyexcel' package to read Excel spreadsheets from a file. I need to know which columns are empty, but have found that for some reason not all empty fields are 'None' type and instead just appear blank. I've been trying to clear out whatever is in there using .replace, but haven't had much luck. I'm not sure if my regular expression is wrong or just doesn't apply to something in the column. I'm still working getting comfortable with Numpy data types and am a little lost.

Regrex I've been trying to use to replace the invisible data:

```
df = df.replace(r'^[?!a-zA-Z0-9_]+$', r'', regex=True)
```

Function to create a list of empty columns:

```
def lister(table, table_name):
try:
    lst = []
    table.replace(to_replace='', value= None)
    for c in table.columns:
        if c == 'NOT USED':
            continue
        elif (table[c].isna().all()) == True:
            print(c)
            lst.append(c)
        else:
            continue
    return lst
```

Comment: are you trying to print columns that are completely null?

Comment: @MattR Yes, right. And it works fine, but there's a conversion problem with some of the completely null columns. They don't show as Numpy none type, they're just blank, and so they don't print. I tried using a regrex to replace any non-numeric data with null to get the blank columns to show as completely null, but it doesn't help.